# Error when building INET, Veins, Veins_inet3, SimuLTE for integration in my simulation

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

The following frameworks are used in `OMNeT++ 5.6.2` for simulation implementation.

- INET Frarmework 3.6.6
- Veins 5.0
- Veins_inet3 (Veins 5.0 subproject)
- SimuLTE 1.0.1

Each framework was imported inside `OMNeT++`. And each framework has a `Project reference` item specified as follows.

- INET Framework => No reference any project
- Veins 5.0 => `INET`, `SimuLTE`
- Veins_inet3 => `INET`, `Veins 5.0`
- SimuLTE => `INET`, `Veins_inet3` and checked `SimuLTE Cars` in `Project Features`

When I build the whole project I get an error like the image below. Sometimes an error related to `ld` occurs.

[image]

[image]

How do I build the project so it is error-free?

Comment: Have you tried Instant Veins? It comes with all the tools you mentioned already correctly set up, ready to run simulations. You can also use it as a basis for comparing how your simulation is set up differently.

Comment: @ChristophSommer I tried using `Instant Veins` but it was slow so I set up a simulation environment locally. It was the original operating environment, but it was a problem that occurred during the reinstallation process because it did not work due to some problem. Fortunately, it is not a problem if you run it in `debug` mode. However, I'm still running into the same issue when building in `release` mode and I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: My only recommendation is to compare your setup to that of Instant Veins, to see where/how they differ. This will be the needed change to make everything work.

Comment: @ChristophSommer Yes, I'll compare `Instant Veins` with my environment. Thanks your advice.